# Does the convergent sequence of convergent sequences converge?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Say for every $d_j$, we have a sequence $\{x_{j_k}\} \in Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_{j_k}$ converges to $d_j$. Then we also have that the sequence $\{d_j\}$ converges to $d$. Can we show (or give a counterexample) that there exists a sequence $\{x_k\} \in Q$ that converges to $d$?

I was thinking if we could simply take the sequence $x_{k_k}$ but not sure if that would imply having to maximize between the infinite number of indices $\geq K$ such that all $|x_{k_k} - d| < \epsilon$ for $k \geq K$.

Comment: More generally, if you have a family of sequences $x_{j,k}$ converging to $d_j$ as $k\to\infty$ with $d_j\to d$ as $j\to\infty$, then for every $n\in\mathbb N$, let $f(n)$ satisfy $\lvert x_{n,f(n)} - d_n\rvert\le\frac 1n$ (note: $f$ can be chosen to be increasing, this is left as an exercise). Then $x_{n,f(n)}\to d$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Your attempt doesn't work as you could have $x_{j_i}=0 [i\le j] =1 [i\gt j]$ and your limits $d_j$ and $d$ would all be $1$, but the limit of your subsequence would be $0$. However you can always make $j$ high enough that $d_j$ is as close as you like to $d$, and then $i$ high enough that $d_{j_i}$ is as close as you like to $d_j$ and that should enable you to complete a proof.

Comment: The statement is true and, btw, it relies on the axiom of dependent choice!